# Cannot implicitly Convert Type string to

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

This is the code which i am using..

using PWServiceProxy

```
PortfolioQueryOptions Query = new PortfolioQueryOptions();
Query.PortfolioTypes = "Funded";
```

I am receiving an error such as

> Cannot implicitly convert type string to PWServiceProxy.PortfolioTypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `PortfolioTypes` is an `enum` with the name `YourEnumType` try this :

```
Query.PortfolioTypes = (YourEnumType) Enum.Parse(typeof(YourEnumType), "Funded", true);
```

Comment: `TrParse()` is faster and type-safe

Answer (score 9):

Seems that `Query.PortfolioTypes` is type of `PWServiceProxy.PortfolioTypes` i.e. [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

So you need to

```
Query.PortfolioTypes = PortfolioTypes.Funded;
```

---

or

```
string str = "Funded"; // or something else
PortfolioTypes pt;
if (Enum.TryParse(str, out pt))
    Query.PortfolioTypes = pt;
else
    throw new Exception("Can't parse input as PortfolioTypes");
```

Comment: +1 that's of course better in the scenario described - parsing should only be done if you are stuck using a string you got from somewhere

Comment: thats not going to work. because i need to pass string to the Query.PortfolioTypes

Comment: @Peddireddy: `PortfolioTypes` is clearly not of type `string` - please share the type with us if it's not `enum`

Comment: Portfolio Type is an object Coming out from PWServiceProxy.

Comment: @Peddireddy: What is it's type?  Try `value.GetType().ToString()`. Or it is `object`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `if (Enum.TryParse<PortfolioTypes>(str, out pt))`

Comment: @Tuzo: compiler automatically determines the type, so if you omit generic type parameter, it will use out variable's type. Also you can specify another type if needed/applicable